# java.awt.image.Kernel and negative values does nothing

Tags: java, image, filter

I've got a problem with java.awt.image.Kernel class.
If I apply positive arguments into it, everything works fine. But when I pass negative ones, it doesn't change image at all.

```
int size = 3;
float[] values = { 1f, -2f, 1f, -2f, 4f, -2f, 1f, -2f, 1f }
Kernel kernel = new Kernel(size, size, values);
ConvolveOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
BufferedImage toReturn = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());
op.filter(image, toReturn);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem too. Changing the type of `BufferedImage` from `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` caused it to work like expected. Apparently negative values don't work when using alpha.